# How to ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY on Views?

Tags: abap, hana

I am currently making old programs HANA-ready. I work with the hints from ACI and I am on delete adjacent duplicates. Mostly an easy task. Just put an ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY and it's fine. However, on inner joins and views I get the following error:

> "ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY" does not work for views. Use "ORDER BY f1 ... fn" instead.

Now my question: How do you handle this?

I don’t really have the time to deep dive in the code and understand the whole program to find a logic based solution. Is there a fast way to sort views so they have always the same order on HANA as they have on R/3?

Answer (score 4):

Views have no technically defined primary keys, so `ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY` does not work. You also can not do something to make it "have always the same order on HANA as they have on R3" because the sort order is determined by whatever database software you are using, and with many of them it can happen that JOINs over multiple tables do **not** always return results in the same order. A nasty source of impossible to reproduce bugs I had to deal with more than once.

But if your view is just one table or an INNER JOIN of two or more tables, then the real primary key of the result set is pretty easy to determine: It's the combinations of all the primary key fields of the tables you join on.

But please note that slapping `ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY` on every `SELECT` is the quick&dirty way of making a program HANA-ready. It's usually much better to think for a couple minutes what sort order would actually make sense in this case.

When the results later get reduced to unique results with `DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES`, then you need to make sure that the internal table is sorted by those fields which get compared here. So when there is a list of fields (like `DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES COMPARING date time bukrs`) then you need to sort by those fields. When there are no fields, then you need to sort by all fields. Which you can actually do much simpler in ABAP with simply `SORT itab`.

Or when the sorting order is indeed completely irrelevant in this particular case, slap on the pseudo-comment `"#EC CI_NOORDER` to the SELECT to clearly communicate that order does not matter here (to both the database and to other developers).

Yes, that takes some time. But converting an older system to S/4HANA is not a task you do in a single day. It's a large project which usually takes months to complete.

Comment: ad: the real primary key for the INNER JOIN case: that's not right. Think of a lookup inner join (e.g. "color code" to "color name") then the primary key of the result is still the PK of the driving table. Primary keys are by definition not reducible, but the minimal combination of columns of which all column values for this record depend on.

Answer (score 3):

No, there’s no magic button in the database that can guess what your desired sort order should be.

Even with other databases ABAP never guaranteed the sort order in the absence of explicit `ORDER BY`.
If the programs depend on that without specifying `ORDER BY` that’s a fault in those programs.

Ad: “no time...” you’re about to pay back technical debt, that got incurred when the programs got developed with that fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you have HANA, then you your system is new enough for CDS views, and *those* can have keys.
So you just need to replace your old database view with a CDS view, add they `key` keyword to the necessary fields and you are done.